# Can we use normalise.css package with react MUI CSS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React project utilizing Material-UI for styling components. I've heard about Normalize.css for consistent browser rendering, and I'm wondering if it's possible to integrate Normalize.css with React MUI.

Specifically, I'm interested in:

Whether using Normalize.css alongside Material-UI is recommended.
Any potential conflicts or compatibility issues between Normalize.css and Material-UI.
Best practices or considerations when combining the two.

I've already searched through the documentation and online resources but couldn't find a clear answer. If anyone has experience or insights on this topic, I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or advice. Thanks in advance!

Attempted Integration: I attempted to include Normalize.css alongside Material-UI by importing it into my project's main stylesheet, which is then included in my root component.

Expected Outcome: I expected that Normalize.css would normalize browser styles across different platforms, ensuring consistent rendering, while Material-UI would handle the custom components and styling according to its design guidelines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.